# How many warrants do I need to exercise to get a stock?

Tags: investing, trading, starting-out-investing, day-trading, warrants

I am getting the following information from the link http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/ipoa.ws

Social Capital Hedosophia Holdings Corp. Warrants, each whole warrant exercisable for one Class A Ordinary Share at an exercise price of $11.50 Quote & Summary Data

Does this mean that I can exercise a warrant and get 1 stock? How do I confirm this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you trade the warrant and the warrant price of $11.50 for one stock.

The warrant is a little like an option, but with a longer term.

If you buy a IPOA.WS warrant then that warrant gives you the option to buy one share of class A stock at $11.50 at a future date.  If in the future, the stock is worth $20, then you make $20 - $11.50 -  per share.  If you buy one IPOA.U, then you get 1/3 of a warrant and 1 share of stock, the warrants will be useless unless you buy in groups of 3 for the IPOA.U.  I didn't see the timeframe of the warrant, they're usually good for 10+ years, and they're currently trading in the $1.5-1.8 range.

To confirm, here's a decent article about how warrants work:
http://www.investopedia.com/articles/04/021704.asp